# How to sort List<List<Integer>> based on the order of element in each inner list?

Tags: sorting

For example, I have a List like

```
[[0, 5, 9],[0, 3, 5], [0, 3, 7], [0, 5, 7], [0, 3, 9], [0, 7, 9], [3, 5, 7]]
```

The expecting results should be like

`[[0, 3, 5], [0, 3, 7], [0, 3, 9], [0, 5, 7], [0, 5, 9], [0, 7, 9], [3, 5, 7]]`

The sorting is based each element in the array. so [0,3,9] should go before [0,5,7].

Thanks so much for any possible solutions!

Comment: My first sort is to override the comparator and compare each element in the list.

Comment: you know comparator, so what's your question?

Comment: No coding language given - I posted an answer for python & c# - the trick is to combine your inner lists to a simple integer and then sort them by it: [0,3,5] => 35,  [0,3,7] => 37, ... ,[3,5,7] => 300+50+7 = 357 etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why so comlicated - its just `int`s - you can multiply them by a fitting 10^n according to importance and add them up. This forms the sort-key and then its a simple sort by integer, ascending:

(C# - you specified no language)

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;

internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<List<int>> l = new List<List<int>> {
            new List<int>{0, 5, 9 },
           new List<int>{0, 3, 5},
           new List<int>{0, 3, 7},
           new List<int>{0, 5, 7},
           new List<int>{0, 3, 9},
           new List<int>{0, 7, 9},
           new List<int>{ 3, 5, 7}
            };

        var sorted = l.OrderBy(sub => sub[0] * 100 + sub[1] * 10 + sub[2]);

        Console.WriteLine("[" + string.Join("],[", sorted.Select(s => string.Join("],[", s))));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

(Python)

```
data = [[0, 5, 9],[0, 3, 5], [0, 3, 7], [0, 5, 7], [0, 3, 9], [0, 7, 9], [3, 5, 7]]

sorteddata = sorted(data, key= lambda x: x[0]*100+x[1]*10+x[2])
print (data)
print (sorteddata)
```

Output:

```
[[0, 5, 9], [0, 3, 5], [0, 3, 7], [0, 5, 7], [0, 3, 9], [0, 7, 9], [3, 5, 7]] => 
    [[0, 3, 5], [0, 3, 7], [0, 3, 9], [0, 5, 7], [0, 5, 9], [0, 7, 9], [3, 5, 7]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a comparison function that compares two lists, then pass you're custom comparison function to your sort function.

Answer (score 0):

My first thought is to override the comparator and compare each element in the list.

```
Collections.sort(res, new Comparator<ArrayList<Integer>>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(ArrayList<Integer> o1, ArrayList<Integer> o2) {
            if (o1.size() == o2.size()){
               for (int i = 0; i < o1.size(); i++){
                   if (o1.get(i) < o2.get(i)){
                       return -1;
                   }else{
                       return 1;
                   }
               }
            }
            return o1.size() - o2.size();
        }
    });
```

However, it doesn't work with the case[[0,3,9,] [0,5,7]], since when we compare 3 and 5, [0, 3, 9] will go first, but when we compare 7 and 9, [0, 5, 7] will go first.

So I try to compare a string instead of a integer:

```
Collections.sort(res, new Comparator<ArrayList<Integer>>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(ArrayList<Integer> o1, ArrayList<Integer> o2) {
            if (o1.size() == o2.size()){
                String s1 = "";
                String s2 = "";
               for (int n1: o1){
                   s1 += n1;
               }
               for (int n2: o2){
                   s2 += n2;
               }
               return s1.compareTo(s2);
            }
            return o1.size() - o2.size();

        }
    });
```