# Sorting List<List<string>>

Tags: c#, sorting, .net-core

I have a List of List which can be of variable but repeated width. For example:

```
var test = new List<List<string>>();
test.Add(new List<string> {"1","2","3"});
test.Add(new List<string> {"1","4","12"});
test.Add(new List<string> {"1","2","9"});
test.Add(new List<string> {"1","4","5"});
test.Add(new List<string> {"6","7","8"});
```

But it could also be:

```
var test = new List<List<string>>();
test.Add(new List<string> {"1","2","3","3","3"});
test.Add(new List<string> {"1","4","12","1","7"});
test.Add(new List<string> {"1","2","9","9","4"});
test.Add(new List<string> {"1","4","5","8","5"});
test.Add(new List<string> {"6","7","8","2","7"});
```

It will never be:

```
var test = new List<List<string>>();
test.Add(new List<string> {"1"});
test.Add(new List<string> {"1","5"});
test.Add(new List<string> {"1","2","3"});
test.Add(new List<string> {"1","5"});
test.Add(new List<string> {"6","7","8"});
```

And I would like to have the list ordered left column to right column like:

```
["1","2","3"];
["1","2","9"];
["1","4","5"];
["1","4","12"];
["6","7","8"];
```

The following is a little test I setup to see what I could come up with (https://dotnetfiddle.net/B5ljig):

```
var test = new List<List<string>>();
test.Add(new List<string> {"1","2","3"});
test.Add(new List<string> {"1","4","5"});
test.Add(new List<string> {"1","2","3"});
test.Add(new List<string> {"1","4","5"});
test.Add(new List<string> {"6","7","8"});

var query = test.AsQueryable();
query = query.OrderBy(a=>a[0]);
var max = categories.Select(a=>a.Count()).Max();
for (int i = 1; i < max; i++)
{
    query = query.ThenBy(a=>a[i]); // Error Here
}
var sorted = query.ToList();
```

Unfortunately the commented line errors with

> 'IQueryable>' does not contain a definition for 'ThenBy' and no accessible extension method 'ThenBy' accepting a first argument of type 'IQueryable>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Any ideas? Thoughts? Better ways.

Comment: You should not add all these `AsQueryable` (excepted maybe the very first). The `IQueryable.OrderBy` should return an `OrderedQueryable` and `IEnumerable` a `IOrderedEnumerable` on which you can apply `ThenBy`

Comment: Why do you need `IQueryable` here? and `ToString()` for strings?

Comment: Also, I don't think you need `ToString` since you already have strings.

Comment: @Pac0 Yes, sorry that was me testing a suggestion elsewhere. I have removed the redundant AsQueryable and ToString. Unfortunately should isn't helping me here.

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski if you think there is a better way than IQueryable, I am all ears.

Comment: So you want to order each nested list, then order the outer list by the first value in each nested list?

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay Order each "Row" by each "Column". Does that make sense?

Comment: The problem is the use of the variable `i` from the loop The variable is captured by the lambda, which means, it has value `3` for all lambdas when the query is executed !

Comment: @neeleshbodgal I am sorry, it's my fault, I modified the fiddle when I was doing my answer. I'm going to update it.

Comment: A simplification will be to convert to List Int. In order to easly handle 1<12<3 that will be the result of string comparaison. Making a IComparer<List<int>> will be easy to. Throw an error is the same is not the same for each index return the value for the first index that where int comparer is not 0.

Comment: query = query.OrderBy(a=>a[0]); In this line, IOrderedQueryable<List<string>> is typecasted to IQueryable<List<string>> hence ThenBy method is not available. Instead  use another variable like var query1 =   query.OrderBy(a=>a[0]). Try again

Comment: closly related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47401181/how-to-sort-listlistinteger-based-on-the-order-of-element-in-each-inner-list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to `Sort` anything using *your own rules*, you can implement a custom *comparer* (`IComparer<T>`), `IComparer<IList<string>>` in this particular case:

```
   public class MyListComparer : IComparer<IList<string>> {
      private static int CompareItems(string left, string right) {
        if (left.StartsWith("-"))
          if (right.StartsWith("-"))
            return -CompareItems(left.TrimStart('-'), right.TrimStart('-'));
          else
            return -1;
        else if (right.StartsWith("-"))
          return 1;

        left = left.TrimStart('0');
        right = right.TrimStart('0');  

        int result = left.Length.CompareTo(right.Length);

        if (result != 0)
          return result;

        for (int i = 0; i < left.Length; ++i) {
          result = left[i] - right[i];

          if (result != 0)
            return result;
        }

        return 0;
      }

      public int Compare(IList<string> x, IList<string> y) {
        if (ReferenceEquals(x, y))
          return 0;
        else if (null == x)
          return -1;
        else if (null == y)
          return 1;

        for (int i = 0; i < Math.Min(x.Count, y.Count); ++i) {
          int result = CompareItems(x[i], y[i]);

          if (result != 0)
            return result;
        }

        return x.Count.CompareTo(y.Count);
      }
    }
```

Then sort:

```
  var test = new List<List<string>>();

  test.Add(new List<string> { "1", "2", "3" });
  test.Add(new List<string> { "1", "4", "12" });
  test.Add(new List<string> { "1", "2", "9" });
  test.Add(new List<string> { "1", "4", "5" });
  test.Add(new List<string> { "6", "7", "8" });

  // Time to sort with a custom comparer
  test.Sort(new MyListComparer());

  string report = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, test
    .Select(line => string.Join(", ", line)));

  Console.Write(report);
```

Outcome:

```
  1, 2, 3
  1, 2, 9
  1, 4, 5
  1, 4, 12
  6, 7, 8
```

you can use the comparer with *Linq* query as well:

```
  var sorted = test.OrderBy(new MyListComparer());
```

Comment: I like it it use the fact that "12" is longer than "3" to say it's bigger. This will how ever fail on "03" vs "12".

Comment: @xdtTransform: Good catch! This problem can be solved with `TrimStart('0')`

Comment: That certainly worked. Its to late for me to dive into the "Why" but I will have a look int detail tomorrow. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is

1) the overuse of `IQueryable`, you don't need it,

2) the fact that `i` is actually *captured*, and when the query is executed, you have all "then by" that use the same i == 3, the last value after the end of the `for` loop! (Hence, an out of bounds exception at runtime)

Here is a working version ([dotnetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Widget/Zq4tTt)):

```
    var query = test.OrderBy(a=>a[0]);
    //var max = test.Select(a=>a.Count()).Max(); // If you say all lists have the same length, use `First(a => a.Count())` instead! And if they don't, then this will lead to an exception.

    for (int i = 1; i < max; i++)
    {
        var j = i; // Intermediary variable so that 'global' i is not captured.
        query = query.ThenBy(a=>a[j]);
    };
    var sorted = query.ToList();
```

On additional note, there are other solutions that use different approaches, already given, I think they feel more "idiomatic" for C# with the `IComparer`

Comment: In `OrderBy` and `ThenBy` I believe we should convert `string` to `int` so that "2" wouldn't be larger than "10".

Comment: that's a good additional point! That's however something OP should confirm. AndrewHarris : do you need _lexicographic_ sort (as the natural sort for `string`) or number sort (as the natural for `int`).

In tha latter case, I'd suggest turning your string to `int` either from start in the data, or during the sort.

Comment: Yes sorry b=my example used numbers for clarity. It needs to be string sort,not numerical sort.

Comment: And really good point on the use of First(). Another of those got so far down the rabbit hole I wasn't seeing the simple stuff.

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues with your code. One is a syntax issue and one is a logic issue.
To remove the compilation error you are seeing, the query variable must be an IOrderedQueryable instead of the IQueryable that you have listed. If you combine the query variable definition and initial ordering in to one line like below, your issue should resolve.

```
var query = test.AsQueryable().OrderBy(a => a[0]);
```

You could also use the IOrderedEnumerable instead using

```
var query = test.OrderBy(a => a[0]);
```

The logic issue is that your code will not produce the result you are expecting. You are ordering the list of the list of strings by its first value before ordering each list of strings. In other words, your initial Orderby needs to be below your for loop. For simplicity I'm simplifying to this Linq expression:

```
var sorted = test
    .Select(x => x.OrderBy(y => y).ToList())
    .OrderBy(x => x[0])
    .ToList();
```

Comment: I think my explaination wasn't clear. Each "Row" needs to be order based on its "Columns". 1,2,2 comes before 1,2,3. 1,1,2 comes before 1,2,2. I cant change the order of the columns within a row. This is hard to explain :/

Comment: In that case, Dmitry's implementation of IComparer<T> is absolutely the correct solution to use. It will allow you to sort with any custom logic you'd like.